# automatically send mail birthday wishes in php without cron

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a user table with date of birth and email address. 
I want to send automatic email for there birthday wishes according date of birth  in there email address. In php with mysql server. Please help me regrading this.

Comment: what current code do you have? tried?

Comment: i dont know what code i used

Comment: What's your issue with using cron?

Comment: What have you done so far, and where did it fail? Please note that SO is not a free code writing service, and please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you extract wish (Birthday and or anniversary) details as excel (date, email, name) and let [wishing app](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app) take care of everything.

At minimal it just need two things **excel file** with wish details (Date, name, email) and a configuration file (**application.properties**) and that is it, you are good to go.

Further there various [options to run](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Running) the application locally (Command line, foreground, background, docker, windows scheduler, unix cron etc) Cloud.

Application is [highly configurable](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Configurations-unleashed) , you can configure various details like:

- Workbook loading options
- Image options to send with wishes.
- SMTP Configurations
- Other application level configurations like, when to send wish, belated wish, logging etc.

  Disclaimer : I am the owner of the application

Answer (score -1):

To automate such tasks you typically have to use cron jobs on a server (that e.g. can launch lynx calling specific php pages). Unless you are pretty sure that a site will have 24/7 clients on a landing page that invokes hidden tasks to send those birthday wishes. Apart from being a bit unsecure in terms of hacking, it has the risk that there are no clients in time on that landing page each day.

Comment: This not the answer to OP's question. The OP explicitly asked: "... without crone ..." (and surely meant cron instead of crone).

Comment: @Binarus; why that harsh? I wrote Narenda Soni that in my opinion there is no real solution for this tasks without using cron. And for both (with or without cron, for when he/she doesn't know how to use cron) I came with a solution.

Comment: I hope I wasn't too harsh. I am respecting that you did try to help the OP, and therefore I did not downvote your answer (that was somebody else). Nevertheless, IMHO, you are not answering the OP's question (the OP obviously is aware of cron, but does not want to use it for some reason). Furthermore, your answer is misleading. We even don't know if the OP is on linux; apart from that, there are at least two widely used packages under Linux which could be used to replace cron (systemd, at), the OP could write an own server etc. Under Windows and other OSs, the situation is similar.